# Apply patch to the code base from java code using any library like SVNKIT

Tags: patch, svnkit

I have a patch file that needs to be applied in the working directory of codebase checked out using SVN. I need to write program to do this. Now I used SVNKIT jar to do (checkout from repository, updating code base, reverting any local changes). Now I could not figure out a way to apply a patch to the code base. Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 1):

With SVNKit, use the "doPatch(java.io.File, java.io.File, boolean, int)" method of the [SVNDiffClient](https://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html) class:

Arguments:

1. the source patch file
2. the target directory
3. "dryRun" - if "true", the patching process is carried out, and full notification feedback is provided, but the working copy is not modified
4. "stripCount" - specifies how many leading path components should be stripped from paths obtained from the patch (usually "0")

Comment: I used this:
svndiffClient.doPatch(PATCH_FILE, destinationDir, false, 0);
Arguments:
PATCH_FILE - patch fileobject
destinationDir - file object with svn check out location
dryRun as false
stripCount as 0

The code runs without any error but the patch is not applied. Can you figure out something?
I even tried with dryRun as true. Not working

Comment: That sounds good to me. Please check again if the paths in the pathfile are correct (i.e. relative to "destinationDir").
In case you are using Windows: I ran into [this bug](https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-691) - I am using svnkit 1.8.12

Comment: When looking into the source code of svnkit-1.7.14.jar, the doPatch method just returns SVNErrorMessage public void doPatch(File absPatchPath, File localAbsPath, boolean dryRun, int stripCount) throws SVNException {
    SVNErrorMessage err = SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorCode.UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE);
    SVNErrorManager.error(err, SVNLogType.WC);
  }